# How can we merge the results of two queries have group by and two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have these two tables: (games)

[image: games table]

and (rounds) table:

[image: rounds table]

I would like to get the game id's, there round count, and the count of how many rounds that player1 wins. I created two sql queries like this:

[image: queries and results]

but I want to get all results in one table. How can I combine the results to be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT game_id, COUNT(*) AS roundsCount, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN winner = player1_id THEN 1 END) As p1WinsCount   
FROM games AS g
INNER JOIN rounds AS r ON g.Id = r.game_id
GROUP BY game_id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a3525/1)

Comment: thanks a lot, this helped me to get the result. what do we call the way of using (case, then .. end). is there any good url to learn more about it?

Comment: @zuhair When a `CASE` expression is used inside a function like `SUM`, `COUNT` etc., then this is called *conditional aggegration*. There are plenty of resources on the web on this topic. Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/310674/Conditional-Sums-in-SQL-Aggregate-Methods) for example.

Comment: When use count() function not need '*'. Plz specify column name.

Comment: @Mukesh This wouldn't make any difference in this case

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the results of 2 separate queries with derived tables:

```
select
  A.gameId, 
  A.roundsCount,
  B.p1WinsCount
from
  (
     select g.Id as gameId, count(r.Id) as roundsCount
     from game g, rounds r
     where g.Id = r.game_id
     group by g.Id
   ) A,
   (
     select g.Id as gameId, count(r.Id) as p1WinsCount
     from game g, rounds r
     where r.winner = g.player1_id
     group by g.Id
    ) B
where
  A.gameId = B.gameId
```

But in this case you can do it a lot simpler too:

```
 select 
   g.Id as gameId, 
   count(r.Id) as roundsCount, 
   sum(case when r.winner = g.player1_id then 1 else 0 end) as p1WinsCount
 from 
   game g
   join rounds r on g.Id = r.game_id
 group by 
   g.Id
```